# constant pool content lost when generating v8's bytecode

Tags: node.js, v8, bytecode

Here is the output generate by execute 'node --print-bytecode --print-bytecode-filter=incrementX index.js  > code.txt'.It lost the constant pool content.Only have the pool size.I tested in Node.js version v8.3.0 and  and v14.2.0, both of them have same output.And i try to execute 'node --print-bytecode --print-bytecode-filter=incrementX index.js > code.txt v8_enable_object_print = true', but it didn't work.

```
[generating bytecode for function: incrementX]
Parameter count 2
Frame size 8
   81 E> 000003FC1A1C4316 @    0 : 93                StackCheck 
   91 S> 000003FC1A1C4317 @    1 : 03 01             LdaSmi [1]
         000003FC1A1C4319 @    3 : 1f fa             Star r0
  105 E> 000003FC1A1C431B @    5 : 21 02 00 03       LdaNamedProperty a0, [0], [3]
  100 E> 000003FC1A1C431F @    9 : 2c fa 05          Add r0, [5]
  110 S> 000003FC1A1C4322 @   12 : 97                Return 
Constant pool (size = 1)
Handler Table (size = 16)
```

This is the example has content.

```
[generating bytecode for function: incrementX]
Parameter count 2
Frame size 8
  12 E> 0x2ddf8802cf6e @    StackCheck
  19 S> 0x2ddf8802cf6f @    LdaSmi [1]
        0x2ddf8802cf71 @    Star r0
  34 E> 0x2ddf8802cf73 @    LdaNamedProperty a0, [0], [4]
  28 E> 0x2ddf8802cf77 @    Add r0, [6]
  36 S> 0x2ddf8802cf7a @    Return
Constant pool (size = 1)
0x2ddf8802cf21: [FixedArray] in OldSpace
 - map = 0x2ddfb2d02309 <Map(HOLEY_ELEMENTS)>
 - length: 1
           0: 0x2ddf8db91611 <String[1]: x>
Handler Table (size = 16)
```

I am searching the answer for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js Bytecode Constant Pool Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992553/node-js-bytecode-constant-pool-output)

Comment: `v8_enable_object_print = true` is a compile-time parameter, it goes into `args.gn` before you compile V8. Or just use a Debug build, which enables object printing by default.